# In-place archive mail's parent id is wrong

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, ews-managed-api

Request a message-delta-API to retrieve emails from Office 365

But responsed email's parent id is different from requested mail folder id.

```
GET users/<user_id>/mailfolders/AAMkADE0YzI2M2ZjLWZmMWQtNGJhYS04ODAwLTQyNGE1MjRhZjBmNAAuAAAAAAA04VsRWcG1QIXIr3qrtsr6AQCQoXa_LYT9R6mod2ub97_KAAAAaLhVAAA=/messages/delta
```

```
"id": "AAMkAGE4NTUwNThkLWQ2ZTMtNDExNS04NDAxLTJlZDk1NmU0MGE2MQBGAAAAAAAfiKJvRm_JQ4jeiUSK2FOEBwCQoXa_LYT9R6mod2ub97_KAAAAaLhVAADJFo_o3DVNT7IA4GCQhOQ3AAAyXPH0AAA=",
"parentFolderId": "AAMkAGE4NTUwNThkLWQ2ZTMtNDExNS04NDAxLTJlZDk1NmU0MGE2MQAuAAAAAAAfiKJvRm_JQ4jeiUSK2FOEAQCQoXa_LYT9R6mod2ub97_KAAAAaLhVAAA=",
```

1. The mail folder id seems to have a strange translation? Maybe it is in some O365 operation like migration or something?

```
mail folder id
AAMkADE0YzI2M2ZjLWZmMWQtNGJhYS04ODAwLTQyNGE1MjRhZjBmNAAuAAAAAAA04VsRWcG1QIXIr3qrtsr6AQCQoXa_LYT9R6mod2ub97_KAAAAaLhVAAA=

email's parentFolderId
AAMkAGE4NTUwNThkLWQ2ZTMtNDExNS04NDAxLTJlZDk1NmU0MGE2MQAuAAAAAAAfiKJvRm_JQ4jeiUSK2FOEAQCQoXa_LYT9R6mod2ub97_KAAAAaLhVAAA=
```

2. Request informat attached, hope it can help for investgation.

```
cache-control →private
client-request-id →b60c6917-3e8e-41db-ac12-e0e36831ab5d
content-encoding →gzip
content-length →29658
content-type →application/json;odata.metadata=minimal;odata.streaming=true;IEEE754Compatible=false;charset=utf-8
date →Thu, 07 Jan 2021 02:59:22 GMT
odata-version →4.0
preference-applied →odata.track-changes
request-id →b60c6917-3e8e-41db-ac12-e0e36831ab5d
strict-transport-security →max-age=31536000
vary →Accept-Encoding
x-ms-ags-diagnostic →{"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"East Asia","Slice":"SliceC","Ring":"3","ScaleUnit":"000","RoleInstance":"AGSFE_IN_9"}}
```

3.This mailfolder is in-place archive mail folder, ews-managed API has the same problem. too

Comment: Try the same with EWS Editor utility and see if you can still repro the issue or not.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same with EWS Editor utility (with same API call) and it works for me. So i would suggest you to try the same.